# How to load package css last in meteor?

Tags: meteor, package

I have added a calendar package in my meteor app, but the css of this package is loading first in the final client css, which is causing the body css to override the calendar styles.

How do I make the package css to load last?

Comment: Don't know about the page but if it is outside of a package, In the client folder create `main.css` file and copy the styles, all files with `main.*` will load last http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

Comment: packages**, trello card for this, https://trello.com/c/mHK2dpr5/68-new-way-of-defining-packages-apps-and-controlling-file-load-order

Comment: @Sasikanth yes I got that from the official documentation but I need to know and understand why the CSS from the packages is loaded first.

Comment: AFAIK, that is how meteor file load order works, first from packages then remianing directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages are loaded before your own files in order to ensure that everything is available and ready to be utilized.

Perhaps you can simply modify the body CSS, given that you are writing it, to not overwrite that calendar.

Comment: I had to eventually do that, but there still needs to be a solution to this, because what happens if we have a css reset in our css, it will reset the css from the packages and will cause inconsistencies.